# using the Background Worker in C#?

Tags: c#, progress-bar

One part of my application works loading of Images from the predefined folder. At this time when loading the images it takes more time. Now I figured out that the progress Bar which can let me to tell the progress of loading.

The Problem I faced is:
I can't able to Integrate the BackgroudWorker, Progress Bar with my function.
For Instance the following is the Background worker and Progress bar code:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Load file list here
    int totalImageCount = 10000;
    // Set maximum value of the progress bar
    progressBar1.Invoke(new Action(() => { progressBar1.Maximum = totalImageCount; }));

    for (int i = 0; i < totalImageCount; i++)
    {
        // Load a single image here
        Thread.Sleep(10);

        // User cancelled loading (form shut down)
        if (e.Cancel) return;
        // Set the progress
        progressBar1.Invoke(new Action(() => { progressBar1.Value = i; }));
    }

    // Cleanup here
}

// Starts the loading
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Start loading images
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

// Stops the loading
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // Stop the loading when the user closes the form
    if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy) backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
}
```

The following is The function which needs to be for Progress Bar

```
 private void LoadImages()
    {
    string imagesPath = (Application.StartupPath + "/UnknownFaces/");
                    string[] extensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png" };
                    var allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(imagesPath);
                    this.imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(256, 250);
                    this.imageList1.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
                    foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in filesSorted)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            this.imageList1.Images.Add(fileInfo.Name,
                                                     Image.FromFile(fileInfo.FullName));
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(fileInfo.FullName + "  is is not a valid image.");
                        }
                    }
                    this.lstView_un.View = View.LargeIcon;
                    lstView_un.LargeImageList = this.imageList1;
                    lstView_un.Items.Clear();
                    for (int j = 0; j < this.imageList1.Images.Count; j++)
                    {
                        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                        item.ImageIndex = j;
                        item.Text = imageList1.Images.Keys[j].ToString();
                        this.lstView_un.Items.Add(item);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Something Wrong happen! "+ex.Message);
                }
    }
```

I think the main routine works are there:

```
 this.lstView_un.View = View.LargeIcon;
                lstView_un.LargeImageList = this.imageList1;
                lstView_un.Items.Clear();
                for (int j = 0; j < this.imageList1.Images.Count; j++)
                {
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                    item.ImageIndex = j;
                    item.Text = imageList1.Images.Keys[j].ToString();
                    this.lstView_un.Items.Add(item);
                }
```

Comment: Look at the documentation for BGW.  It has specific support built in for updating progress, with examples of how to use it.

Comment: I believe in your idea. But I'm in a limited time to complete my existing application. This is the case that hangs me to read more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slow part of your code is actually the loop that reads the files, not the loop that populates your `ListView`.

The best way to report or otherwise present progress state in the UI from `BackgroundWorker` is to use the `ProgressChanged` event. However, the code example you are working from will work as well. That is, just update the `ProgressBar` object directly from your worker code. It fails to take full advantage of the features that `BackgroundWorker` provides (and indeed, raises the question of why bother with `BackgroundWorker` if you're not going to use its features), but it will work.

For example:

```
var allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(imagesPath);
this.imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(256, 250);
this.imageList1.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;

// Set the maximum value based on the number of files you get
progressBar1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => { progressBar1.Maximum = filesSorted.Count(); }));

foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in filesSorted)
{
    try
    {
        this.imageList1.Images.Add(fileInfo.Name,
        Image.FromFile(fileInfo.FullName));
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fileInfo.FullName + "  is is not a valid image.");
    }

    // Update the ProgressBar, incrementing by 1 for each iteration of the loop
    progressBar1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => progressBar1.Increment(1)));
}
```

**Note:** your code example is incomplete, and doesn't make sense even as a snippet. One problem in particular is that you retrieve the file names into the array `allfiles`, but you are iterating on a completely different collection, `filesSorted`. I did my best with the code you provided to work with, but since the code you posted wouldn't work as-is, you may well have to make some minor adjustments to the example I've provided to get it to do what you want.

If you are unable to figure this out with the above, please provide [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably illustrates your scenario and what precisely you're having trouble figuring out.

Comment: great help! It works now with your provided edit. But can I add the percentage of counting in-front of the progress bar.

Comment: Of course. You can put whatever you want in your UI. The only requirement is that you update the UI in the UI thread, which is what using the `Invoke()` method allows. The above example invokes a method that has a single statement: `progressBar1.Increment(1);`. But you can invoke any method you want, including one that e.g. also sets a `Label.Text` property to a string representing the percentage value.

Comment: Peter, you are the best for me, I have seen your suggestion soundness. Can you show me how can I set label.Text to set for percentage?

Comment: Just add the statement `label1.Text = progressBar1.Value * 100 / progressBar1.Maximum;` to the method you invoke. That, of course, assumes that you've named the `Label` control as `label1`. Use whatever the actual name of your control is, in the actual code.

Comment: Peter, it counts and shows only the number which final value (100%), but not shows like, 1%, 2%, 3%... when loading.

Comment: Then you didn't put the assignment in the correct place. Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I'm afraid I can't offer anything more specific than that.

Comment: Just it is enough for me Peter. Thank you very much! for your maximum effort. Just it is enough nothing left, bye!